# Index out of bound exception with normal dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, parallel-processing, indexoutofboundsexception

This is my scenario .  I have a normal dictionary which is being updated in another plugin. I do not have access to that. These are my steps which update this dictionary

1. Inside foreach i am adding to the dictionary . something like this

   ```
    foreach (var detail in items)
           {
             Plugin.LoadImage(detail );//This is inside another plugin.
           }
   ```
2. next step, i have something like this

   ```
            Parallel.ForEach(items, processorCount, mDetail=>
           {
             Plugin.UnLoadImage(detail);//This is inside another plugin.
            }
   ```

Inside LoadImage we are loading image and updating cache. cache is normal dictionary. In LoadImage, we are adding to cache, and in unLoadImage, we are removing entry from cache

This whole process is inside some loop, which takes 50-50 items in each loop. 
First 2-3 sets are fine. but after some sets, in the 1st step, i am getting Index out of bound of exception.

Since i am running multiple threads, and removing items from dictionary from other thread and then again adding some items in different thread, it is causing this condition?

I cannot use concurrent dictionary here. Because dictionary is in another plugin.

Is there any workaround for this? I can avoid parallel processing and make it sequential but it is really time consuming process and i want it to finish quickly.

I have seen lot other posts regarding this. They are suggesting to use ConcurrentDictionary. But my case here is different since i am depending on Third party plugin.

Comment: If cache is a standard dictionary then it is not safe to modify on multiple threads. If you can't change the type to a thread-safe collection then you've got to stop trying to modify it on multiple threads.

Comment: If you really have to use multiple threads, create a lock and only modify the dictionary within the lock. Do all other processing work outside the lock. Whether that works depends on who else can access `Cache`  outside the lock.

Comment: Thanks mike. If i am not wrong, if i use lock it will be again more of sequential operation right?

Comment: Yes it will be sequential, but that's what you are limited to when you have to mutable, shared memory between multiple threads. Where is the other processing that you are doing? That should probably be outside the lock.

Comment: There is no `Add` method on the built jn Dictionary class that accepts a single argument

Comment: @mikez Yes. Currently it is inside lock. I placed inside because it wont take much time. I can move it outside

Comment: @SamAxe hey sam! as i explained Add is handled by third party plugin.

Comment: Something doesn't add up. If "it won't take much time" what's the point of multiple threads here? Adding to a dictionary does not take much time either. You can add 100k objects to a dictionary in 10ms, but you are using multiple threads because "it is really time consuming process and i want it to finish quickly".

Comment: Ok. My mistake. This is the  abstract version whatever i have shared . Actually we are calling just one method called "laodImage" from plugin inside foreach loop. It will load the image and update the cache. Loading image part will take time. Loading and updating is inside this plugin. I just peeked into the code shared just the updating part. in order to make image loading faster i used parallel threads.Hope this clears your doubt